# org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector while trying to locate an element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, xpath-1.0

My element is displayed as:

```
<a class="main-item" href="#">Business Loans</a>
```

xpath is:

```
//*[@id='main-nav']/ul/li[1]/a[1]']
```

This returns `invalid element locator`

```
//*[@id='main-nav']/ul/li[1]/a']

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main-nav']/ul/li[1]/a[1]']"))
```

I am trying to get the element.

Comment: Remove `'` from `/a[1]']`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Here is the simple xpath.

```
//*[@id='main-nav]//a[@class='main-item' and .='Business Loans']
```

If you want to use the one which you mentioned, here is the corrected.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main-nav']/ul/li[1]/a[1]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try contains function in xpath, it can extract all the elements which matches a particular text value

```
//a[contains(text(),'Business Loans')]
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector
```

...implies that your `xpath` was not a valid one.

You can't use the single quote i.e. **`'`** or the double quote i.e. **`"`** for both `By` value and *attribute* values.

---

### Solution

You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#main-nav a.main-item"));
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='main-item' and text()='Business Loans']"));
  ```

Answer (score -2):

my element is displayed as

Add

my xpath is

//button[@id="addNewRecordButton" ]

I got error message as
InvalidSelectorException
how to fix this exception and click specific element.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. You should create a new question for this.